# Understanding POST statuses/filter Rate Limit

Tags: twitter

I need to do a keyword based data fetching on Twitter. I looked up the documentation and "POST statuses/filter" seemed like the best option. However, I do not understand how the rate limiting works. Does this mean that I can fire this request repeatedly? If yes, at what rate should I do so? Or do I have to fire the request only once and keep on getting data continuously? They have given clear explanations for the REST API. There's even a page showing the number of requests permissible in a 15 minute window for each REST API method. I was unable to find something similar for "POST statuses/filter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've been researching about using the Streaming API there aren't any rate limits because you just make the request once to open the connection, then you keep it open and you are sent a stream (hence the name) of tweets.

> Once applications establish a connection to a streaming endpoint, they
>   are delivered a feed of Tweets, without needing to worry about polling
>   or REST API rate limits.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public